# fatal error with "$ git push "branch_name"

Tags: git, github

Why is this not pushing to my newly created branch?

```
PS `\team_test> git checkout -b 123123
Switched to a new branch '123123'
PS `> git push
fatal: The current branch 123123 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin 123123

PS ~> git push --set-upstream origin 123123
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'bla.bla.bla' to the list of known hosts.
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 351 bytes | 175.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
```

I was used to push to origin  (`git push --set-upstream origin 123123`), why can't I just push to *my own* branch without `origin`? Why can't I just print "git push" when I'm in my branch?

Comment: After `git push --set upstream`, you should be able to type `git push` without additional arguments to push to the matching upstream branch.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the problem is. After you set up the upstream branch you were able to push!?

Comment: Yes, I can to push to THIS current branch, but when i create a new one - I must do th same, I meen. -set upstream

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that this is "your" branch. It is a *new* branch so it doesn't exist on the remote. Therefore, in order to push, you have to say what you want done with it. You cannot just say `git push`.

You have two choices. One is to say *every single time* what you want done with the branch:

```
git push origin 123123
```

However, it is more convenience to say this, *once*:

```
git push -u origin 123123
```

The `-u` is a shortcut for setting the upstream. *Now* you will be able to say `git push` forever on this branch.

You have to do this for *every* new branch you create on your local repo that you want to push.

Comment: Well, but is a command  "git checkout -b" must to create a new branch in a cloned reository?Or its just local repository?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the repository was created. `git checkout -b` makes a new local branch, it doesn't exist on the remote, and everything I said applies.

Comment: total: "git checkout -b"  -  creates a new branch, but in my local repo, but when i want to push it to origin, So I want to clearly say!!!! )))))   git push origin 123123 (or use "-u" for permanet saying "git push" for this current branch)

Comment: This is a big + to your karma ))))) Thank you whery much again)))